# Unit Testing with AngularJS 1.5+ using $componentController - Double data binding

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, jestjs

I'm currently facing a problem with my testing code.
An example is better than 10 thousands words so here it is.

```
describe('Initilazing', () => {

    let $componentController, scope;
    beforeEach(inject((_$componentController_, _$rootScope_) => {
        $componentController = _$componentController_;
        scope = _$rootScope_.$new();
        scope.name = 'Testing...';
    }));

    it('Should have the parent scope double binded', () => {
        let $ctrl = $componentController('sasInput', scope, { api: scope.sasInput });
        $ctrl.onInit();

        scope.$apply();
        expect(scope.sasInput).not.toBeUndefined();
    });
});


class SasInputController() {
    constructor() {
      'ngInject';
    }


    $onInit() {
        this.api = { clear: this.clear.bind(this) };
    }

    clear() {
        this.input = null;
    }
}

export default {
    ...
    bindings: {
        api: '='
    }
}
```

Here's the deal, inside my component, scope.sasInput should be updated with the current component api on the $onInit. But it is not.
What do I do wrong here ?

Can you help, please ?
Thank you.

Comment: Can you please show your component definition and `$onInit` handler of component's controller?

Comment: Edited. For clarity I didn't put all the export parameters. Bindings are the one interesting here.

Comment: When doing `this.api = {  clear: ...` you are losing reference to the `scope` object that was passed to the component. Using a bit more complex model could help you to avoid this. Take a look at [this gist with mentioned approach](https://gist.github.com/barsurfer/cf6858365caab5b6a453fd0d95017ccb), hope it helps.

Comment: I'll try this tomorrow at work. Come back to you as soon as I tested this :) If this works, I don't understand why tbh. Because  the code works perfectly in a browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by @estus (thanks to him), you can't test two-way data bindings with `$componentController`. You have to create a new `angular.Element` containing your component and use `$compile` with a call to `scope.$digest()` to do so.
Here's the final solution

```
... // previously created a scope with $rootScope.$new() ($rootScope injected with inject())
it("should double bind", () => {
    const element = angular.element("<your-component two-way='api'></your component>");
    inject(($compile) => {
        const compiledElement = $compile(element)(scope);
        scope.$digest();
        expect(scope.api).not.toBeUndefined();
    });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

All that `$componentController` does is getting a controller from component definition and instantiating it. If `$onInit` needs to be tested, it should be called directly:

```
$ctrl.$onInit();
```

`$onInit` is lifecycle hook and a part of compilation process. In order for a component to be tested in whole, it should be compiled with `$compile`, as any other directive.

Comment: Yes, sorry it was my mistake. I forgot to put the $onInit() call on the post.
Still not working tho'

Comment: There's no way how a controller can propagate the changes back to `scope` because it has no reference to it. You can't use $componentController to test two-way `=` binding. Use $compile. $componentController is for testing class logic.

Comment: I went for $componentController because using $compile raised an error about unsafe templateURL. We use $templateCache with gulp to convert HTML file to JS module containing all template cache definition. And I don't know how I can make this work with Jasmine tbh :(